# Analogue of ComposeShader in Flutter

Tags: flutter, shader, gradient

I'm searching of analogue of Androids ComposeShader in Flutter.

My code in Android app

```
SweepGradient sweepGradient = new SweepGradient(width / 2, height / 2, colors, null);
RadialGradient radialGradient = new RadialGradient(width / 2, height / 2, colorWheelRadius, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00FFFFFF, TileMode.CLAMP);
ComposeShader composeShader = new ComposeShader(sweepGradient, radialGradient, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

I try to reproduce this code in Flutter, but I can't find ComposeShader

```
SweepGradient sweepGradient = SweepGradient(colors: colors);
RadialGradient radialGradient = RadialGradient(colors: radialColors, tileMode: TileMode.clamp);
```

Is there an analogue in Flutter? or similar class.

Comment: since there is no such thing, maybe multiple `ShaderMask`s would do the trick...

Comment: Thank you for help. Yes, it works. First I create CustomPaint Widget with SweepGradient as child of ShaderMask (RadialGradient)

Comment: @RomanKazov, please, provide the solution.